# how do I create a trailing pattern in processing?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to create a program, wherein the ellipses revolve around the center screen and add a trailing pattern to it. I'm using ArrayList in processing to store the old vector then draw it, but it's not rendering. Or am I doing things wrong? The part where I wrote it is on the bottom part, thank you.

```
Particle[] part = new Particle[10];
int len = 10;

void setup(){
  size(1000,1000,P2D);
  //fullScreen();
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    part[i] = new Particle();
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    part[i].show();
    part[i].update();
    part[i].trail();
  }
}

class Particle{

  float r,angle,d;
  PVector pos = new PVector();
  ArrayList<PVector> history = new ArrayList<PVector>();

  Particle(){
    angle = random(20,360);
    r = random(20,300);
    pos.x = width/2 + cos(angle) * r;
    pos.y = height/2 + sin(angle) * r;
  }

  void show(){
    stroke(0,0,255);
    ellipse(pos.x,pos.y,5,5);
    //line(x,y,width/2,height/2);
  }

  void update(){
    pos.x = width/2 + cos(angle) * r;
    pos.y = height/2 + sin(angle) * r;
    angle += random(0.001,0.01);
  }

  void trail(){
    history.add(pos);

    if(history.size() > 50){
      history.remove(0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < history.size(); i++){
      PVector prev = history.get(i);
      ellipse(prev.x,prev.y,5,5);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

> ```
> history.add(pos);
> ```

then you do not create a new `PVector` object. You just add a reference to the attribute `pos` to the array list `history`. When `pos` is changed, then still all elements of `history` refer to `pos`. There exist just one `PVecor` object for each `Particle`.

Create a [`copy`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_copy_.html) of `pos` when you add it to `history`, to solve the issue:

```py
history.add(pos.copy());
```